# Any alternatives to Ubigraph?

Tags: charts, visualization, data-visualization

[Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) is a different way to create interactive user interfaces with the purpose of visualizing huge amounts of data. Its [visualizations](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Demos/random_binary_tree.html) are simply stunning.

The problem is that the project seems to be dead (last blog post in 2008) and is still in alpha. I am considering using it as my preferred visualization GUI, but the alpha tag scares me. Do you know of any alternatives to Ubigraph with similar functionality? Would you consider creating an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into ubigraph as well, and was deeply fascinated by it. Unfortunately, its license said that you couldn't redistribute it.

Inspired by Ubigraph, I've spent the past ten years putting together fourd.js. As the name implies, it runs in javascript, i.e. Node.js or browser js. Large graphs are handled depending on the specs of your machine, but on a good machine you can easily display a thousand vertices.

Check out the [FourDSocketProxy](https://github.com/thwee-alchemist/fourdsocketproxy), which runs as a Node's library, opening a browser window.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/a/5330) paying particular attention to the items in `bold`. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1349158/edit) so it follows the guidelines. Please note that software recommendation questions (like this one) are off-topic and shouldn't actually be answered.

Comment: Do you have any demo videos showing how it looks? I believe this is essential for attracting attention.

Answer (score 2):

Ubigraph does seem very pretty, but 3D visualizations suffer from occlusion problems that can significantly hamper their usefulness. It is usually better to have multiple 2D views side-by-side.

What size datasets are you interested in analyzing? There are several open-source tools for analyzing graph or network datasets that vary in the features available and the size they can handle. [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) is a great introductory tool that integrates network analysis into Excel 2007/2010 (*Disclaimer: I'm an advisor for it*). Other tools like [Gephi](http://gephi.org/), [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), and especially [Large Graph Layout](http://lgl.sourceforge.net/) may scale better for larger graphs, but are not as easy to use.  [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/) and [UCINet](http://www.analytictech.com/ucinet/) are some proprietary alternatives.